# Python - naming parameters from enumerate

Tags: python, enumerate

**Question:**

Take the following:

```py
def a(the_enumerate: enumerate):
   print("index: " + str(the_enumerate[0]), character: " + the_enumerate[1])

map(a, enumerate("test"))
```

Is there a way of naming the index and the current element (character) in a better way than:

```py
index: int = the_enumerate[0]
character: int = the_enumerate[1]
```

Perhaps it would be something like this:

```py
def a(the_enumerate: enumerate(index: int, character: str)):
   print("index: " + str(the_enumerate[0]), character: " + the_enumerate[1])

map(a, enumerate("test"))
```

**Context**:

My method feels like it could be written in a "nicer" way and i'm just going through a journey of what can be done:

```py
# Version 1
def convert_pascal_casing_to_real_sentence(string_to_convert: str) -> str:
    def casing_check(the_enumerate: enumerate):
        result: str = ""

        if the_enumerate[0] != 0:
            result = " " +  the_enumerate[1].lower() if the_enumerate[1].isupper() else the_enumerate[1]
        else: 
            result = the_enumerate[1]
            
        return result

    return "".join(map(casing_check, enumerate(string_to_convert)))

# Version 2
def convert_pascal_casing_to_real_sentence(string_to_convert: str) -> str:
    output: str = ""

    for index, character in enumerate(string_to_convert):
        if index != 0:
            output += " " + character.lower() if character.isupper() else character
        else: 
            output += character

    return output

# Calling one of the two methods
print(convert_pascal_casing_to_real_sentence("HelloWorld"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack the `enumerate` values as follow:

```py
def a(the_enumerate: enumerate):
    index, char = the_enumerate
    print(f"index: {index} character: {char}")
```

giving you:

```
index: 0 character: t
index: 1 character: e
index: 2 character: s
index: 3 character: t
```

Comment: Ah! Now that's more like it! Thank you! Also thanks for the f".." (I didn't know you could do that)

Comment: no problem, have a nice day ^^

Comment: Any way of typing those too? As in `index: int, character: str = the_enumerate`?

Comment: For `f-string` you can check out this resource: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python

Comment: Nevermind I found that you can annotate the types first, and then unpack into them. Cheers. The word `unpack` is helpful to know.

Comment: you can also type `the_enumerate` as `Tuple[int, str]`, mypy seems happy about it

Comment: Oh. that's cool! Thank you! I see now that enumerate returns `Iterator[tuple[int, _T]]`. Makes sense.